# Can a client release an .ipa binary that was created with my developer portal certificates?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, phonegap, provisioning-profile

I am for the first time, creating an app for a client (rather than for a company I have full access to). I use the phonegap method which includes generating the app's provisioning profile and certificates in the developer portal, using phonegap to package it all as a releasable .ipa file.

Are there any limitations on me generating the .ipa file in phonegap, sending it to them, and them releasing the binary through their itunes connect? Or - will it get caught up when they upload because they didn't generate the certificates?

Answer (score 0):

They are almost definitely going to need to sign the file with your production certificate. You can export it from Xcode if you use it and have them add it to their keychain.